# MongoDB performing poor with better configuration machine

Tags: mongodb, performance

We have two mongo servers one for testing and one for production each of them have a collection named `images` with ~700M documents.

```
{
    _id
    MovieId
    ...
}
```

We have the index on `_id` and `MovieId`

We are running the queries of the following format

```
db.images.find({MovieId:1234})
```

**QA Config:**

```
256GB of RAM with RAID disk
```

**Prod Config:**

```
700GB of RAM with SSD mirror
```

mongod configuration (/etc/mongod.conf)

**QA:**

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/mongodb_data"
   journal:
     enabled: false
   engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
     engineConfig:
        cacheSizeGB: 256
setParameter:
   wiredTigerConcurrentReadTransactions: 256
```

**Prod:**

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/mongodb_data"
   directoryPerDB: true
   journal:
     enabled: false
   engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
     engineConfig:
        cacheSizeGB: 600
setParameter:
   wiredTigerConcurrentReadTransactions: 256
```

With the better configuration for the prod server, it should perform better than QA server. Surprisingly it is running very slow compared to QA Server.

I checked current ops (using `db.currentOp()`) on both servers under the same load, lot of queries on the prod server takes 10-20 seconds, but on the QA server No query takes more than 1 second.

The queries are initiated from Mapreduce jobs.

I need help in identifying the problem.

[Edit]: Mongo Version 3.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a difference in the number of **open files** and, **max user processes** between our Staging and Production servers. I checked it by using the command `ulimit -a`

**Staging:**

```
 open files                      (-n) 32768
 pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
 POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
 real-time priority              (-r) 0
 stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
 cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
 max user processes              (-u) 32768
```

**Prod:**

```
 open files                      (-n) 16384
 pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
 POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
 real-time priority              (-r) 0
 stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
 cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
 max user processes              (-u) *16384*
```

After I changed the two settings on prod, it started giving better performance. Thanks @Gaurav for advising me on this.

Comment: increasing the number of open file descriptors is a good idea. apart from that you may try  to incerase net.maxIncomingConnections too. BTW, I have noticed that your stack sizze is set to something 10240, this might result tcp stack to consume too much mem. you may try to lower it to 1024 or 2048.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your mongo queries in multiple ways.

Start with your index usage using below command :
db.images.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] )

If this don't give you any useful information, then check the execution plan of the slow queries using : 
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
db.system.profile.find().pretty()

db.system.profile will give you complete profile of your queries.

Comment: Gaurav, Is the command db.images.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ) correct? I am getting some errors while running it.assert: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$indexStats'",
 "code" : 16436,
 "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed

Comment: yes, it's working for me. Refer to mongo doc at : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/

Comment: which mongo version are you using?

Comment: I am using mongo 3.0.11. I think indexStats in new in 3.2, that's why I am not able to execute

Comment: It works for 3.2 version. Try using .explain("executionStats") in you find queries or explain:true in aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Sorry, did not get what you said. can you give the query which can be executed on 3.0.11?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123935/discussion-between-ravi-chandra-and-gaurav-kumar).